# SSD is acting strange in Asus K75VM laptop

Tags: ssd, bios, sata, asus-laptop

I bought an Intel 530 SSD, 240GB, which supports SATA 3.
The laptop is an ASUS A75VM-TY0877V, running Windows 8.1. There are not many drivers installed, as this is just a clean install (and yes, I am going to do a clean install on the SSD too, if I could get it to work).

There is a lot going on:

- It doesn't show up in BIOS.
- I was able to successfully install and use Ubuntu.
- The BIOS does show the bootable Ubuntu partition on it.
- Testing the disk with `dd` gives me a writing speed of about 260MB/s, while it should reach speeds up to 490MB/s.
- Windows 8 installation just hangs at the 'starting setup'. The hard drive LED on the front was constantly on, but turned off after approximately 10 minutes.

Research I have done:
I found that a lot of people had problems with a SATA 3 SSD. Even though the chipset does support SATA 3. Besides, if the motherboard doesn't support SATA 3 it should switch to something lower. I have also read that the manufacturer just turned off SATA 3 support and that it would require a simple BIOS modification to make that option available (more on that later). Also some people report having a SATA 3 SSD working successfully.
In the Windows Disk Manager, I can see the disk, and select format. After a while a message pops up that it can't format the drive (and nothing more).

Things I have tried:

- Updated the BIOS
- Tried to use diskpart to clean the drive. However, when trying to enter diskpart (from the Windows setup), it just hangs at the line `on computer: MINWINPC`, and I am unable to type the next commands.
- Tried the SSD in both drive bays.
- Setting SATA mode to IDE. This makes the drive show up in BIOS (and I have not tried more).

Modifying BIOS:
As said earlier, someone reported that SATA 3 was just turned off. I have used a lot of tools, but it all comes down to the point that I opened the extracted ROM file with amibcp and found most menus were duplicated. The first ones having a lot of options and the latter ones having a lot less. Both are set to be displayed, even though I only see the less complicated one. Furthermore, when looking in the complicated menu, in SATA configuration (in amibcp), I see the controller speed default is set to gen3. I don't know if this is just part of the ROM or if this is also set in the BIOS like this. So I disabled the less advanced menu and saved the ROM. Then I tried to flash it to the ROM with all kinds of software, but they all report that the BIOS is write protected.

What I am looking for:
Getting SATA 3 and Windows to run on the SSD. I know a lot of people have reported it as not working, but those posts are from 2012, and I was hoping this issue was gone (as we have newer SSDs and drivers now), or that someone has found a fix in the meantime. Otherwise I think I am just going to return the drive and going for a SATA 2 SSD.

EDIT:
As for Ubuntu:
I just saw that the bootloader in my BIOS directed to the Hitachi disk (that is the original disk). Sadly, this time when letting my PC boot from that I just got a grub rescue prompt. I don't know what is going on, as the first boot (directly after installation) was going fine.

EDIT2:
I installed IRST (Intel Rapid Storage Device) drivers. The first boot windows kept hanging at the loading screen. So I turned the laptop off (after waiting for 10 minutes). Next boot works properly. And right now I have formatted the drive as NTFS. Looking good. Intel SSD Toolbox is currently optimizing the pc and I will run a diagnostic after that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem ,but I found this one:
"if you can get SATA III from 1 HDD bay, and 1 ODD bay, then they (2x SATA III) are fully accounted for.
HM76 has 2x SATA III ports, and 4x SATA II.
http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www...pset-brief.pdf"
=>
If you have 1.HDD + 1SSD + 1DVD ROM = 3 sata3 ,but chipset support is 2x

Comment: I tried the SSD only, without the HDD or DVD bay. This didn't work. Besides, the HDD and DVD are only sata 2.

Comment: Check your URL. It's broken.

Answer (score 0):

> There are not many drivers installed, as this is just a clean install
>   (and yes, I am going to do a clean install on the SSD too, if I could
>   get it to work).

That's odd! It's a clean install? It doesn't sound *that* clean to me. There are not *many* drivers installed? But there are a *few* drivers installed, right? So something *is* installed then?

> Windows 8 installation just hangs at the 'starting setup'. The hard
>   drive LED on the front was constantly on, but turned off after
>   approximately 10 minutes.

It's normal for Windows 8 installation to hang a little at the "starting setup" screen. It appears as though it has hanged, but it's actually working behind the scene (the "starting setup" teaser). Give it enough time. What is enough time? You be the judge of that. I would say 1 minute is too short, and 60 minutes is too long.

> I have also read that the manufacturer just turned off SATA 3 support
>   and that it would require a simple BIOS modification to make that
>   option available.

You go by rumors? I doubt that they all have the exact same configuration of that particular model. What does your documentation say? Does it support SATA 3 or SATA 2? Also, don't confuse SATA 3 (Gbps) with SATA 2.0.

Is AHCI enabled? Do you have that option? Enable it if so. Also try disabling it, and run the ports in legacy IDE mode. Does the behavior change? Can you install Windows and boot it? Don't complicate things with dual booting at this stage! Keep it simple! Pick only one OS for testing. I suggest Windows at first.

Running in IDE mode is not as bad as not being able to install and boot into any OS at all. Also, don't confuse IDE with SATA 2. With IDE enabled, you're still on SATA 3 if that's what your motherboard supports. If it supports SATA 2 only and the disk is SATA 3, it will switch to SATA 2 compatibility mode.

> Modifying BIOS [...] Then I tried to flash it to the ROM with all
>   kinds of software, but they all report that the BIOS is write
>   protected.

See now you're in over your head, *and* you're seeing double! You don't modify and flash BIOS images at random like that. That is only asking for trouble. If you have conducted extensive testing and troubleshooting, and you have concluded that the fault lies with your system BIOS, then I recommend that you update it to the latest version. That's about as much as anyone can do that's humanly possible. Without requiring an M.Eng, M.Tech or MSc.Tech degree, and the time and effort spent rewriting the BIOS or redesigning the entire motherboard. It should prove much easier to just buy a new computer...

> There is a lot going on

You can say that again!

> Ubuntu... bootloader... BIOS... Hitachi... IRST... Windows... NTFS...
>   SSD Toolbox...

You're all over the place. Just step back and relax! Get some fresh air and come back again. Think it through. What is the main issue here? What is your goal with all this and how do you get to it?

If need be, replace your SSD with a different model. You could try getting one that's specifically built with SATA 2 support, as you suggested. Your SSD may also be bad (as in bad apple), so it's good to be able to test it on a different computer to rule that out. If it's bad you will have to replace it under a warranty claim, or the return policy of the retailer.

As for IRST (Intel Rapid Storage Device), or the Matrix Storage drivers, I would suggest not using those. In my experience I have seen that the provided Windows AHCI or fake-RAID drivers are better optimized and better performing than the Intel ones. So unless you're installing Windows XP, feel free to skip those pesky IRST/IMSM/IRST drivers. If you decide to install them anyway, then accept the fact that you will not be able to easily remove them from the system and reconfigure the provided Windows drivers to perform at their best: it's easier to reinstall Windows altogether.

**Update**

---

- Clean install on HDD works. Clean install on SSD doesn't.

Thank you for the clarification!

> From the clean install on the HDD, the SSD wasn't even detected.

Inside Windows you mean? Was it detected by BIOS?

The thing about "rumors" is that they spread fast, and they do not always apply to the particular model you have, nor are they trustworthy. Be skeptical! That's what I was saying. When in doubt, go by the book! When desparate... fine, take the longshot. But accept the potential risk then of damaging the device. I don't recommend it though.

```
ASUS A75VM Intel
HM76 Express Chipset
```

That's the info I found on their Taiwanese website. And yes, it's true that the chipset does support SATA 3.0.
Source: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/performance-chipsets/mobile-chipset-hm76.html

It's strange how there is not much info to go on for this not too old model. But here's the English user's manual: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/K75A/E6944_eManual_K75A_Z106.pdf

I was unable to find a service manual. That is often more useful to have at hand.

> The SSD wasn't even detected.

So not detected by BIOS then?

- Installing Windows to SSD didn't work. Installing Ubuntu to SSD
  worked partially.

Thank you for the clarification!

It's needless to say, but I'll say it anyway: have you tried removing the battery? Oftentimes, when you are dealing with a strange problem like this it's not enough to just reboot the operating system, or to do a cold boot. I recommend that you completely re-energize the computer for the chips to re-initilize.

Comment: Bummer I can only use 500 characters. But let me try to put it in multiple comments then. Yes I have tried a lot, some outside the boundaries. At least I've shown I didn't come here to post a "help doesn't work". I tried to do some research and fiddling around already. - 
It was a clean install on the HDD, and I was going to reinstall on the SSD thereafter. I know the installer was busy, and I let it run for a long time. On the HDD it didn't do this. From the clean install on the HDD, the SSD wasn't even detected.

Comment: "You go by rumors?" at least it was worth a shot (and now that you're objecting this, why would I trust your post?). And I don't know what the exact documentation said. Can't find it anymore, besides a general laptop manual. At least the chipset (HM76) **should** support it. And that's the info I found. So I just quickly tried to see if I could make the BIOS change manually. Apparently I haven't figured out, __BUT__ I did __learn__ things from it. IMHO that's even more important.

I tried combinations of settings including enabling and disabling AHCI, legacy IDE etc etc, no positive result.

Comment: "If it supports SATA 2 only and the disk is SATA 3, it will switch to SATA 2 compatibility mode."
What a coincidence! Now I just wish that worked, but it didn't (and I am wondering why this valuable info is missing from my question). The SSD wasn't even detected.
"Can you install Windows and boot it?"
Like said, I couldn't get the installer to work. It just didn't want to install on the SSD. AND I wasn't trying to dive into dual boot already (overwriting isn't dual-booting). My goal was to verify whether I could install Ubuntu on the SSD (which worked partially, as mentioned in my question).

Comment: "then I recommend that you update it to the latest version". Again, please read my post: "Updated the BIOS"

"See now you're in over your head [...] You're all over the place." Exactly! I'm trying to dive in and not give up so quickly. Every piece of information was invaluable to me, thus I jumped from point to point, trying to nail the problem.
However I did return the device a couple days after I made the post (perfect service on this local store), and thus I can't test any of your 'advice'.
Tested the SSD on multiple computers, and it works like a charm.

Comment: The reason why it **should** be something with the motherboard itself, is because the only thing I can find online on the combination of this motherboard with a SATA 3 SSD is problems. And as mentioned, it **should** switch to SATA 2 compatibility, which it didn't.
I haven't yet bought a SATA 2 SSD, and do not plan on doing so anymore. It's already time to plan for a new __desktop__ pc.

Comment: Last but not least, no upvote. I don't feel comfortable with this disparaging post against me, exactly when the only thing I was trying to do is showing what I've already tried (which a lot of Stackoverflow questions lack, and why I've stopped answering questions there).

And that was the end of this long splitpost.

Comment: @MarijnS95 According to some of those rumors on the web, it may be possible to use a HDD caddy to install an SSD in this laptop. Some go as far as claiming that the chipset doesn't support SATA 3 at all. But since you have already given up on the idea it's probably not worth much to you anyway. It looks like ASUS made a poo poo with this one. So yes, it's most likely a bad BIOS or motherboard, or both. It's good to know when to give up.

Comment: @MarijnS95 I apologize for my "disparaging" post. I did not mean to be disrespectful. I just found some conflicting statements in your question, and it was not well structured. So I felt like you were just stating your own conclusions and findings rather than asking a question. I understand it's a difficult problem, but that's all the more reason to structure the question better.

Comment: I've also read about the caddy, however to me it's weird to remove the DVD drive while having 2 2.5" slots. ... Now I'm dazzled, I don't know how to ask a better question anymore. I always feel that most questions lack even the tiniest research or interest in the subject. That's why I've shown what I already tried and researched (and so people won't suggest these things again, or tell me how to do it better according to that). True, that did obscure the question a bit. And now I see your updated answer, I'll write a response up. Thanks for trying to help me out!

Comment: ... I might still consider getting another SATA 3 disk, just to try it again. ... From your updated answer, I tried most things. Like I said in my question, "There is a lot going on:". It is __not__ detected by the BIOS (and thus not bootable from, which is my first concern). However, I was able to install Ubuntu on it, and it was usable after the first automatic reboot (but not thereafter, as the BIOS couldn't detect it). I'm not sure anymore about the detection in Windows. IIRC it did show up under device manager but I couldn't format it nor (obviously) mount it. And I vaguely remember ...

Comment: ... the Windows installer detecting the disk, but not able to install onto it for some error message (which I don't know anymore). "I was unable to find a service manual. That is often more useful to have at hand." exactly, me neither, only the user manual which is not of any use in this case. I don't know anymore what I did with the power, I think I've unplugged all of it, but like I said, not sure. All in all, I feel a strong need to buy the SSD again to do some more testing (great return policy on this shop).

Comment: What BIOS version did you test with? I just noticed that the latest version is from 2014/12/19 and it's version "234". So it's a few months newer than your original question. According to release notes they fixed some fan related issues. But they may have made other minor changes that they don't mention. If you try it again, make sure to get the latest version. Hopefully they will release another update that may just be the right one.

Comment: What I mean by re-energizing is that you remove the battery pack, and that you also clear the CMOS. You can do this prior to a BIOS flash, then flash the BIOS, load optimized default settings, and you can re-energize it once more just to do it thoroughly. I would also suggest that you test a Samsung or a SanDisk SSD.

Comment: I've used the latest available when I posted the question, so that's 232. However 233 seems to fix some HDD related issue. As you say even though it might not be in the changelog, it's worth a try. - I've taken out every power part (power supply, battery and IIRC also the CMOS battery). But I might have to retry resetting the BIOS. - I quickly checked and I'm running 234 already.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? I'm facing the same issue here with the same laptop.